# Can't identify initialization type

Tags: c++, initialization

I came across this code, and realized that I can not recall the type of initialization used, nor its supposed behavior. 
`Point p=(3,2);`only seems to pass the latter value (2 in this case) as an argument to the constructor, so that the PrintOut shows something like `x=2 y=5` as opposed to the expected `x=3 y=2`

```
class Point{
public:
    Point(int x=5,int y=5):a(x),b(y){};
    void printOut()const{
        cout<<"x= "<<a<<"y= "<<b<<endl;}
private:
     int a,b;
};

void main(){
    Point p=(3,2);
}
```

Comment: Make use of your compiler's warnings. GCC gives me *warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect*, which is enough to search for the comma operator and answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Point p = (3, 2);` doesn't call the constructor with 2 arguments, but rather calls it with 1 argument, `2`. That's because of the **comma operator**, which basically throws the result of the first expression (`3`) away, and returns the last one (`2`).

And so the constructor is called with one passed argument, in this case `2` and the default argument, `5`, is used.

If you want to call the constructor with 2 arguments, you have several choices:

- `Point p(3, 2);`
- `Point p = Point(3, 2);`
- `Point p = { 3, 2 };` (C++11)
- `Point p{ 3, 2 };` (C++11)

Answer (score 1):

`Point p = (3,2)` is equivalent to `Point p = 2`, which in turn is the same as `Point p = Point(2)`, hence the observed behavior. Read up on the comma operator in C++.